# RobotFramework to delete older folder or file

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to delete folders/files when its modified date is older than today date <5 days.

below is the sample test that I written in Robot Framework.

The execution of test is passed and all content is deleted.

This example, I have set the current year to 2022 so 2022 not equal to 2023 and deletion should triggered, just for testing purpose.

**How do I set the test to delete content which modified date older than 5 days in actual test?**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem


*** Variables ***
${curr_y}    2022
${curr_m}    01

*** Test Cases ***
Old Files
#   ${curr_y}   ${curr_m}   Get Time    year,month

    Log To Console      'current year is = ${curr_y}'
    Log To Console      'current month is = ${curr_m}'
    ${files}=   List Files In Directory  C:/trydel/ver1    absolute=True
    FOR     ${file}     IN  @{files}
        ${y}    ${m} =  Get Modified Time   ${file} year,month
            Log To Console      'modified year is = ${y}'
            Log To Console      'modified month is = ${m}'
        IF  '${curr_y}' != '${y}'
            Empty Directory    C:/trydel/ver1
        ELSE IF      '${curr_m}' != '${m}'
            Empty Directory    C:/trydel/ver1
        END
    END
```

Comment: Are you sure the steps in the condition are executed? What happens when you try to run **Remove Directory** without any conditions?

Comment: Remove Directory not working

Answer (score 1):

I see few errors in your code.

First, you are listing files from `C:/trydel/ver1` directory and if your working directory is not the same any attempts to operate on these files (in way you do it) will fail. You should add to keyword `List Files In Directory` argument `absolute=${True}`.

Next you are checking some info about files, but than trying to use `Remove File` keyword on directory. You should pass path to file (that's why we want absolute path in previous step) to this keyword.

Finally, if I understand your requirements correctly you should add check whether directory is empty at the end and if yes delete it.

Comment: added the absolute=Ture (main post edited), when use Remove File - error C:\trydel\ver1 is not a file, when use Remove Directory - error Directory C:\trydel\ver1 is not empty

Comment: Remove Directory    C:/trydel/ver1    recursive=True     <- this somehow works but it deleted the directory 'ver1' , I wan to retain this folder.

Comment: ok I use another keyword Empty directory and works now.

Comment: If you want to delete only files user `Remove File    ${file}`

Comment: Empty directory will delete everything, no matter what date files has

Comment: then how do I make it really compare date and delete the older content only?